# Is there a way to view the history of all remote access to/and from a PC?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, history

My PC runs using Window 10, is a Dell Vostro SSD and lately I found out that someone remotely accessed my PC.  I have now closed this access route down but I would like to know if there is a way of seeing the history of this somewhere on my PC, on maybe Event Viewer, or elsewhere?  I believe this remote access may have been going on over the last six to nine months max. Need help here.

Comment: What software exactly did they use to access your system?  It had to be third-party software since they not only would need to have a username and password to access if the malicious access was through a RDP client.  Please [edit] your question to include this vital information required to answer your question

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying to your question Ramhound but I’ve been in work - I believe they accessed my pc through Network Sharing on Windows 10 Pro, as we are both in the same building on the same router. I don’t know how they got the login details of my pc but they did. I need to be able to see history of when my pc was remotely accessed this way. I would have thought Event Viewer would show this, or is there another way? Could do with seeing the IP address, or other identifying data in the history of the remote pc.

Comment: They didn’t need access to your machine specifically, they were provided access, when file sharing was enabled.  I don’t believe file sharing will be logged, since it was explicitly, enabled.

Comment: I realise that physical access wasn’t needed. All ‘channels’  that I had (curiously) never ‘opened’ or configured for permission, have now been secured but all passwords held in my Microsoft account for my PC have been compromised, amongst other sensitive documents. I have my work cut out for me over the next several days, sorting this mess out, but I would have thought that some ‘footprint’ would have been left on my hard drive to show the history of the remote access, at least the log ins! Surely?

Comment: Is this a machine connected to an AD domain?  File sharing wouldn’t leak your MS credentials

Comment: We simply share a BT router. Nothing fancy. Both PCs run Windows 10 Pro. I just don’t understand how the other PC could remotely access mine without me configuring things my end and, for everyone’s info out there, my pc,et al  isin a room that is always padlocked when I’m away (with a padlock and hasp that cannot be pocked/unscrewed etc) I really don’t understand how come there isn’t a trail to be found somewhere on my hard drive...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123323/discussion-between-ramhound-and-vesper007).